# Seperate a reducer that is too large - getting error

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, react-redux

I want to add a `distanceFromPlaceValue` reducer inside a `location` reducer - because I have this shape of redux store:

```
import { Map } from 'immutable'
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native'

const searchForm = Map(
  {
    'categories': [],
    // 'mealTypes': [],
    'location': {
      'locationInput': '',
      'place': {},
      'position': {},
      'distanceFromPlaceValue': 10,
      'distanceFromPlaceUnit': 'kilometer',
      'autocompleteResults': {}
    },
    'keywords': ''
  }
)

var { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window')
const ASPECT_RATIO = width / height
const LATITUDE = 19.0760
const LONGITUDE = 72.8777

const LATITUDE_DELTA = 0.01
const LONGITUDE_DELTA = LATITUDE_DELTA * ASPECT_RATIO

const region = Map(
  {
    region: {
      latitude: LATITUDE,
      longitude: LONGITUDE,
      latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
      longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA
    }
  }
)

const map = Map(
  region: region
)

const searchPage = Map(
  {
    'isMenuOpen': true
  }
)

const initialState = Map(
  {
    searchForm: searchForm,
    searchPage: searchPage,
    map: map
  }
)

export default initialState
```

and I didn't add the `distanceFromPlaceValue` case to the `location` reducer and don't really want to - that reducer is getting too large.

Here is my attempt:

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers(
  {
    searchForm: combineReducers(
      {
        keywords,
        categories,
        location: combineReducers({ location, distanceFromPlaceValue })
      }),
    searchPage,
    map
  }
)
```

Getting this error:

> The previous state received by the reducer is of unexpected type.
>   Expected argument to be an instance of Immutable.Collection or
>   Immutable.Record with the following properties: "location",
>   "distanceFromPlaceValue".

I'm doing something wrong in combineReducers. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`combineReducers` will nest both `location` and `distanceFromPlaceValue` a level deeper than I think you intend, so you will end up with a structure like:

```
{
    'keywords': ''
    'categories': [],
    'location': {
      'location': {
        'locationInput': '',
        'place': {},
        'position': {},
        'autocompleteResults': {}
      }
      'distanceFromPlaceValue': {
        'distanceFromPlaceValue': 10,
        'distanceFromPlaceUnit': 'kilometer'
      }
    }
  }
```

instead of merged together like in the `searchForm` const.

Take a read of the Redux docs on going [beyond `combineReducers`](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/BeyondCombineReducers.html) and then think about what you want your state structure to look like in the end.

If you still want to merge the two reducers, rather than combine them into a nested structure, there are [plenty of other libraries](https://github.com/markerikson/redux-ecosystem-links/blob/master/reducers.md) for combining reducers in different ways for different effects.

I have used [redux-concatenate-reducers](https://github.com/ryo33/redux-concatenate-reducers) to do this before, but not with an ImmutableJS structure, so it may not work out of the box for you

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers(
  {
    searchForm: combineReducers(
      {
        keywords,
        categories,
        location: concatenateReducers([location, distanceFromPlaceValue])
      }),
    searchPage,
    map
  }
)
```